# Using Weights to Draw a Graph with NetworkX

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

I have a list of edges:

```
[[0,0,0], [0,1,1], [0,2,1], [2,3,2], ....[n,m,t]]
```

Where index 0 is a node, index 1 in the list is a node to, and index 2 is the weight value.

What I want to do is something like this:

````
```
     0
   /  \
  1    2 All values of weights of 1
       \
        3 all values of weight of 2

```
````

Orientation does not matter, it's just easier to draw vertically in the editor.
I would like to export this using matplotlib.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the list of edges you presented representative of all your data? If it is, you don't even need the weights to draw the image you want (given your example).

In the code below I'm using [`graphviz_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout.html) to calculate the graph/tree layout. Note that the code is written for Python 2. Again, I'm using only the edges info without considering weights.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[0,0,0], [0,1,1], [0,2,1], [2,3,2]]
G = nx.Graph()

for row in data:
    G.add_edge(row[0], row[1])

pos = nx.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')  # compute tree layout
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=900, node_color='w')  # draw tree and show node names
plt.show()  # show image
```

Output:

[image]